# How are jokers colored in decks with more than two jokers?

Tags: playing-cards

So, normally you have two jokers, a big joker and a little joker. The big one is sometimes distinguished by being red (or colored). How does it work with decks with 4 or more jokers? Is is supposed to alternate black, red, black, red, or is only one supposed to be red, or should the red thing just be avoided with > 2 jokers and some other scheme used to identify their rank?

Comment: Ok, I just had a look around... you guys do use this site for regular old playing cards too, right?

Comment: @Autohpil Yes. It's not all Magic questions, we swear. :)

Comment: Hahah I was tempted to tag it with that, had to look around for [tag:rules]

Comment: To delete your account, follow these guidelines (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) and contact SE directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one 4-joker commercial deck I've seen used 2 black and 2 red.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you remember if there was any way to tell which pair of red-black jokers outranked the other?

Comment: Hmm actually I guess red should always outrank black since it's like a trump suit. I'm still not sure how I should distinguish their rank though.

Comment: One of the two blacks was the trademark. The reds were identical.

Comment: Good enough for me. I'm going to alternate black/red and put little dots under the center of the card to represent their rank, no dots for the lowest, the most dots for the highest, unless anyone has a better suggestion. That should be pretty scalable.

Comment: Jokers aren't normally differentiated by rank in the games I've seen where jokers are used.

Comment: I guess I've only ever really used jokers in spades; I know in that case if two people throw jokers they both act as high trumps so one needs to outrank the other. Now that I think about it, though, I'm wondering if some decks have extra jokers as cards you can write on if you lose another card? I've never played with more than two jokers, I just assumed up until now that the extra ones were used in some game though.

Comment: This is the strangest accepted answer I have seen. One example apparently explains how decks with 4+ Jokers are supposed to be colored.

Comment: @user1873 4-joker single-decks are so bloody rare as to be next-to-impossible to buy. Special order kind of rare.

Comment: @GGG What game are you needing joker ordering for? The trick taking games I've encountered with wilds, 1st one played takes it. And many normal decks have two identical jokers; red/black is common, but not entirely standard. Everything else I've encountered simply requires the joker substitute for a valid card

Comment: @aramis I'm not entirely sure they need to be ranked, I just feel like they should, just in case. I'm not sure what game they'd need to be ranked in, except for trick-taking games. I guess the whoever-goes-first thing can kind of be explained if you treat each joker as being its own separate untrumpable trump suit. I just want to accommodate any set of rules basically.

Comment: @GGG since I've never seen a set of rules for ranking jokers in any game, I really think you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @aramis there are definitely [variations of spades](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spades#Trump_variations) that differentiate the jokers (although none use more than two AFAIK). I want my deck to be as flexible as possible :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no common convention for 4 Jokers.

According to Wikipedia

> There are usually two Jokers per deck, often noticeably different. For instance, Bicycle Playing Cards prints their company's guarantee claim on only one. More common traits are the appearance of colored and black/non-colored Jokers.

and other [websites](http://cardshistory.com/joker-card-history.htm), there are normally only two jokers. The qualities of which, including appearance were probably borrowed from the Tarrot trump cards the Magacian/Juggler and (which is red in color, and outranks) the Fool (which is black in color), both of which have the apperance of a court jester.

Comment: I had a deck of cheap playing cards I bought at the dollar store that had four jokers. I don't remember what they looked like now, though.

Answer (score 1):

The Maverick brand of playing cards (U.S. Playing Card Co.) is one example that sometimes has 2 jokers that simply say, "Maverick" on them and two that show the logo.  Each design is in red on one and blue on the other.

To the best of my knowledge, there's no standard for ranking jokers.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I am trying to conceptualize jokers in a way that resolves them with the other cards and this is consistent with suits and rank... in this case two "ranks" of jokers in each "suit" for a total of four cards.

Answer (score 1):

Most playing card decks I played with here in Hungary usually come with 3 jokers. They have circled stars in the corners. Two of the jokers have black stars, one of them have red.